# Node of Dom Parser to get title from a html page

Tags: php, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

this the html page:

```
<div class="gs_ri">
   <h3 class="gs_rt">
     <span class="gs_ctc">
     <span class="gs_ct1">[BOOK]</span>
     <span class="gs_ct2">[B]</span></span>
     <a href="http://example.com" onmousedown="">Title</a></h3>
<div class="gs_a">A</div>
<div class="gs_rs">B</div>
<div class="gs_fl"><a href="">C</a> <a href="">D</a> <a href=""</a></div></div></div>  
<div class="gs_r"><div class="gs_ggs gs_fl"><button type="button" id="gs_ggsB2" class="gs_btnFI gs_in_ib gs_btn_half">
     <span class="gs_wr"><span class="gs_bg"></span>
     <span class="gs_lbl"></span>
     <span class="gs_ico"></span></span></button>
<div class="gs_md_wp" id="gs_ggsW2"><a href="http://example.pdf" onmousedown=""
```

I'm a little confused to determine the node.

I wanna get `http://example.com` and `Title`

I thought there are 2 ways to get them:

it's a sibling of the `<span>`:

```
 foreach($html->find('span[class=gs_ctc2] ') as $link){
    $link = $link->next_sibling();
    echo $link->plaintext;
    echo $link->href;
}
```

but it does not work.

the second, I take `<h3 class="gs_rt">` as parent, so it's the sibling of last child

```
foreach($html->find('h3[class=gs_rt] a') as $link){
    $link = $link->last_child()->next_sibling();
    echo $link->plaintext;
    echo $link->href;
}
```

it also does not work. I think that I am not understanding yet abot node dom tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to select a sibling.

With `h3[class=gs_rt] a` you are already targeting the respective `<a>` tag. So just extract the desired values from there. You can, however, simplify that selector as follows:

```
foreach($html->find('h3.gs_rt a') as $link){
    echo $link->plaintext;
    echo $link->href;
}
```

**EDIT**

With regard to the comment, I think, what you want is something like this, but I'm not sure and your code above is quite a mess (please use proper indention!)

```
foreach($html->find('h3.gs_rt') as $block){
    $link = $block->find( 'a' );
    echo $link->plaintext;
    echo $link->href;

    $otherLink = $block->find( 'div[class=gs_md_wp] a' );
    // do stuff with that $otherLink
}
```

Comment: sorry, I have one question more, sir. I've added html page in above. I can get the `http://example.pdf` (in the last line) by `find('div[class=gs_md_wp]') as $docLink` `$link = $docLink->first_child();` If I wanna group it with your code. How to determine the node? should it be ->

Comment: `foreach($html->find('h3.gs_rt a') as $link){
  foreach($link->parent()->parent()->parent()->find('div[class=gs_md_wp]') as $docLink)` ? thanks in advance :)

Comment: @rosen_ I'm not sure about Simple Html DOM, but the edited code should work, if it works like most DOM parsers.

Answer (score 0):

add id to the href

```
<a id="myid" href="http://example.com" onmousedown="javascript:get_title('#myid')">Title</a></h3>

function get_title(i){
var h =$(i).attr('href');  
var t =$(i).text(); 
 alert('the link is (' + h + ' ) and the title is (' + t + ' )');
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to use simple html dom parser, sir :)